# Laravel query not binding values correctly

Tags: laravel

My query is returning the wrong results and I think it is because the final parameter (minutes) is not being binded to the query. when I get the querylog everything seems fine but the wrong results are being returned. If I putthe minutes parameter directly into the query it returns the right results as expected but this value needs to be a variable.

To explain the query it is counting all records until the total minutes hit a set number, in my example im using 500.

This query works and returns results as expected:

```
DB::select('SELECT NULL AS session_total_charges, NULL AS call_date, NULL AS inbound_duration, NULL AS total
  FROM dual
 WHERE @total := 0 
 UNION ALL
SELECT session_total_charges, call_date, inbound_duration,  @total := @total + inbound_duration AS total
 FROM (SELECT * FROM records  ORDER BY call_date) C where calling_user =:user and call_date LIKE :date AND outbound_zone_id IN ("UKX","UKM","UKLR","UKNR") and @total < 500', ["user"=>$user, "date"=>$date]);
```

This query does not work and only returns one row

```
DB::select('SELECT NULL AS session_total_charges, NULL AS call_date, NULL AS inbound_duration, NULL AS total
  FROM dual
 WHERE @total := 0 
 UNION ALL
SELECT session_total_charges, call_date, inbound_duration,  @total := @total + inbound_duration AS total
 FROM (SELECT * FROM records  ORDER BY call_date) C where calling_user =:user and call_date LIKE :date AND outbound_zone_id IN ("UKX","UKM","UKLR","UKNR") and @total < :minutes', ["user"=>$user, "date"=>$date, "minutes"=>$minutes]);


[query] => SELECT NULL AS session_total_charges, NULL AS call_date, NULL AS inbound_duration, NULL AS total


    FROM dual
     WHERE @total := 0 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT session_total_charges, call_date, inbound_duration,  @total := @total +  inbound_duration AS total
     FROM (SELECT * FROM records  ORDER BY call_date) C where calling_user =:user and call_date LIKE :date AND outbound_zone_id IN ("UKX","UKM","UKLR","UKNR") and @total < :minutes
              [bindings] => Array
                  (
                     [user] => T-M000005251-009
                     [minutes] => 500
                     [date] => 2016-12-%%
                   )



//Result using bindings (only one row returned)
     [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [session_total_charges] => 0.014125
                [call_date] => 2016-12-01 09:12:39
                [inbound_duration] => 113
                [total] => 113
            )

//Result with values inserted directly into query(correct result returned)

     [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [session_total_charges] => 0.014125
                [call_date] => 2016-12-01 09:12:39
                [inbound_duration] => 113
                [total] => 113
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [session_total_charges] => 0.04733333
                [call_date] => 2016-12-01 09:18:16
                [inbound_duration] => 142
                [total] => 255
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [session_total_charges] => 0.03866667
                [call_date] => 2016-12-01 09:22:21
                [inbound_duration] => 116
                [total] => 371
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [session_total_charges] => 0.012625
                [call_date] => 2016-12-01 09:29:24
                [inbound_duration] => 101
                [total] => 472
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [session_total_charges] => 0.0505
                [call_date] => 2016-12-01 12:03:16
                [inbound_duration] => 404
                [total] => 876
            )
```

Comment: Post your query please.

Comment: @devk the query is in the original post at the top

Comment: Sorry I meant the code that executes the query.

Comment: @devk ok, ive added it

Comment: Okay let me get this straight. The query you posted works, but if you do: `... and @total < :amount', ["user"=>$user, "date"=>$date, 'amount' => 500]);` it doesn't work? And you would like to get this to work?

Comment: Btw the `DB::select(...)` statement you posted directly after "This query does not work and only returns one row" does not actually contain `:minutes` it has 500 hardcoded as well.

Comment: @devk yes thats right + thanks for pointing it out, ive changed it now. do you know why it isnt working?